# Meaning of "science" and "formal"

Tags: meaning

The definition of logic is: the science of thinking about or explaining the reason for something using formal methods.

Which definitions of science from [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/science) or [MW](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/science) apply to the above definition of logic?

And formal means very correct here?

Comment: That's a **very** poor definition of [logic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/). I wouldn't trust any reference that provides it. And _formal_ does **not** mean "very correct"; it means "considering form only". I.e, meaning is irrelevant -- only form matters.

Comment: However, in non technical sense both definitions are adegute.

Comment: @Carlo_R.  They're... what?

Comment: @cornbreadninja: Argh...! I want say: adequate. Sorry.

Comment: I'm kinda confused :( My english is pretty bad. I kinda understand what logical means though like a logical argument. From OALD logical means: following or able to follow the rules of logic in which ideas or facts are based on other true ideas or facts. It's just the term logic that baffles me.

Comment: @JohnLawler The definitions are from learner's dictionaries so the language is intended to be simpler (sacrificing the precision that you require). But for the OP, back to being pedantic: both definitions mention 'natural' or 'physical' world, so technically logic would then -not- be considered a science. But this is really a philosophical situation, applicable to any language, not just English. How are those terms defined in your native language?

Comment: Epistemologically, logic is mathematics. That is, it's an entirely mental activity and has nothing intrinsic to do with the physical world. **Except** that humans created math and logic in order to model the physical world, so our perceptions of it are built-in. This is the main reason why math and logic are useful in science, even though they don't deal with data, but with symbols -- sometimes, if you have well-developed symbols, and you move around those symbols **just right**, you get an answer you didn't know before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That definition of logic is not too bad. However, in that context, "formal" means taking only form into account.

Whether or not logic is a science is a deep, philosophical question. For example, one of the science definitions you linked to is "knowledge about or study of the natural world based on facts learned through experiments and observation". Consider a common property of logic -- that both a statement and its converse cannot be true. Is that "knowledge about ... the natural world"? Do we learn that by observation?

Really, it gets down to semantics. Logic is what it is. If you want to call that part of science, then fine. If not, then not. But it's silly to try to parse definitions that way. Definitions are explanations, not tests you can apply. A sensible definition of "car" could begin "a means of transportation", but a toy car is certainly a car even though it's not a means of transportation.

Comment: And when you say form, what does that mean?

Comment: @Theo: Structure as opposed to meaning. For example, "All men are mortal. Socrates is a man. Therefore Socrates is mortal." has the same structure as "All pligips are moton. Zonk is a pligip. Therefore Zonk is moton." However, one has a meaning and the other doesn't.